# Azure Traffic Manager Need to change DNS completely?

Tags: azure, dns

We have an on premise infrastructure. We use our own DNS server. To use Azure Disaster Recovery, do we need to change the DNS resolver to Azure? It should be a big impact and risk to change the resolver for the whole on premise infrastructure.

Now:

```
On premise DNS--->Actual resolver(not Azure)
```

It has to be necessarily like this?:

```
On premise DNS-->Azure resolver
```

Is not that a big change for a on premise datacenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to change to Azure DNS in order to use Azure Traffic Manager, there are instances where it might be beneficial but since you have not shared your setup its hard to say if you are hitting any of those use cases.

Comment: If users access to the on-premise with domain "ABC.com", when on premise fails, how will they get to "ABC.com" if the resolvers are not in Azure? I mean, the resolvers are in Mexico, users DNS request will go to Mexico not to Azure.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused, traffic manager will handle the request AFTER your DNS resolves the needed services, normally you use a CNAME in your DNS to point to traffic manager and traffic manager keeps track of any service for that URL on prem or cloud does not matter as long as its publicly available which is a requirement, also just beware  you cannot create CNAMES for apex(root) domains maybe thats your confusion because if thats your use case you hvae to use Azure DNS OR a redirect

Comment: So I need to add a CNAME to our DNS, but will this impact the normal DNS requests today? The normal requests (no failover) will start to ask Azure DNS?

Comment: It depends on your setup, I do not have enough details to say for sure but if setup correctly it wont affect anything else